# Display category description for only one category in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I need to display the description of only one category in Wordpress. I can think the code only in pseudo-code, can help me with right code? 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/category_description

In pseudocode some like this:

If $category_id == 3 show the the description of category 3 
else
show nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: <?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>  isn't this what youre looking for? or <?php echo category_description(3); ?> inside the parameters put your category id and it will return the description of category with the id 3

Comment: Yes, but the description of category 3 will be showed in all other categories. I want to display the category of only one, for example 3 and in other categories to display nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the category id in question, you can download this plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/reveal-ids-for-wp-admin-25/.

For example, if you want description for a category called **'News'**, with category id as 2, then you should have something like this:
`<?php echo category_description(2); ?>`,

But to display the description of one category where your theme does not readily output category description, you can simply add
`<?php echo category_description( $category_id ); ?>` to your **archive.php** header or wherever you want to have the description displayed.

You can as well display other category descriptions with the same code. Description for **"News"**, **"Money"** etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo category_description(3); ?>
```

It's all in the link you posted.

This code will display the description of the category with the id number 3. If you want the description of the category with the id 4 you replace the number inside the `()`  like :

```
<?php echo category_description(4); ?>
```

Comment: I think will display the description of category 4 in all categories, right? Or I don't understand ... I edit the archive.php file.